# MongoDB get average of dictfield / embedded document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

I have a MongoDB document like this:

```
{
  ...
  score: 200,
  timing: {
    rT: 124
  },
  utc_timestamp: ISODate("2014-10-19T04:45:04.772Z")
}
```

I can get an average of the `score` using this query:

```
System._get_collection().aggregate([
            { "$match": {
                "system_id": system.id,
                "utc_timestamp": {
                    "$gte": datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) - datetime.timedelta(days=1),
                    "$lt": datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
                }
            }},
            { "$group": {
                "_id": { "$dayOfYear": "$utc_timestamp" },
                "delay": { "$avg": "$score" },
                "up": {
                    "$sum": { "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$result", 405 ]}, 1, 0
                    ]}
                },
                "total_count": { "$sum": 1 }
            }},
            { "$project": {
                "airtime": {
                    "$cond": [
                        { "$eq": [ "$up", 0 ] },
                        0,
                        { "$multiply" : [{"$divide": [ "$up", "$total_count" ]}, 100] }
                    ]
                },
                "delay": 1
            }}
        ])
```

Note the line:

`"delay": { "$avg": "$score" },`

How do I get an average by the `rT` field inside the `timing` dictionary?

This does not work:

`{ "$avg": "$timing.rT" }`

Comment: How "does not work"? The `{ "$avg": "$timing.rT" }` looks alright and should work.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the average is '0' so it is working. If you want to an answer that the syntax is correct, I'm happy to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of `{ "$avg": "$timing.rT" }` is correct and should work fine.